How can I express an operator acting on a subspace of a Hilbert space with outer products?
Let us take a $f$-body space with $\hat{H}$ as the Hamiltonian. We take a general state $|\Psi\rangle=|\phi_{1}\cdot\cdot\phi_{f}\rangle$, where $\phi_j$ can be thought as the state of the $j$th particle. Let $E$ be the energy of the given state given by
$$E=\langle \Psi | \hat{H}|\Psi\rangle$$
Now we define $\hat{\mathcal{H}}^{k}$ as an operator acting on the space of the $k$-th particle as :
$$E=\langle \phi_k |\hat{\mathcal{H}}^{k}|\phi_k\rangle$$
My Question : From the above statement, is it legal to write down
$$\hat{\mathcal{H}}^k=E\ |\phi_k\rangle\langle\phi_k| \ \ \ \rm{?}$$
We can see that that the above expression does immediately satisfy the original definition. However, I cannot understand how may I rigorously derive this.

What do you know about tensor products (of Hilbert spaces) and operators thereon?

The statement $E=\langle \Psi | \hat{H}|\Psi\rangle$ doesn't completely specify the single-particle operator, because as far as I can tell $\phi_j$ is one single-particle state, not all of them, and in addition, diagonal elements don't completely specify an operator. Are you intending that $phi_j$ represent a complete eigenbasis for the single-particle $\mathcal{H}$?

@TobiasFünke , my knowledge of tensor product of Hilbert spaces is preliminary at best. To answer your question "how much do I know" - I think the section [F - Tensor product of state spaces] from "Quantum Mechanics Volume I by Claude Cohen-Tannoudji" is a good representation.
